# Null value error in build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
22:29:49.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:29:49.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
22:29:49.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:29:49.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
22:29:49.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] null value in entry: annotationProcessorOutputFolder=null
22:29:49.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:29:49.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
22:29:49.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
22:29:49.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
22:29:49.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
22:29:49.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
22:29:49.585 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 21s
```

Comment: Try deleting the .gradle folder containing the local cache and rebuilding the project again.

Comment: how to delete the gradle folder? i mean which folder...

Comment: Check your project folder. You may have to enable visibility of hidden files. Or alternatively delete with cmd or terminal. Also, have you tries "rebuild project"?

Answer (score 0):

Jus try clean, and invalidate and restart. It might solve the issue.